# VBA - ADODB.Connection to read from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

Does using ADODB.Connection to read data from Excel files actually open the excel files?


Is there a performance benefit from using ADODB vs opening the file through VBA using GetObject() and reading the data (with screen updating = false)? 

GetObject() seems to sometime take a while to open the file depending on the file. I would like a more "lightweight" alternative to pulling data from the excel file.

Comment: Although it is subjective, I feel an ADO connection would involve less overhead than having the full application via GetObject.  Do you need it to not open the file?  Do you need a feature Excel would provide or just access to the data?

Comment: I need to access the data, and I would also like to pull it into a worksheet for further processing.
I don't need it to not open the file, per se. I just want to find a method (or the best method) that has less overhead if possible.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed your additional info.  ADO all the way for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need the functionalities inherent to Excel, I would usually go with an ADO connection.

```
Dim cn as ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\MyFolder\MyWorkbook.xls;" & _
"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    .Open
End With
```